# How can I import the wavesurfer.js in my Angular 4 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, video.js, wavesurfer.js

I'm using [Video.js](https://videojs.com/) in my Ionic 3 app for videos and audios, and all works fine.
But now, I want to use the [Video.js Wavesufer plugin](https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-wavesurfer) for audios.

I installed the plugin via npm:

```
npm install videojs-wavesurfer --save (plugin)
npm install wavesurfer.js --save (dependency)
```

And imported them in my component.ts:

```
import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';
import VideojsWavesurfer from 'videojs-wavesurfer';
```

And I called `videojs` function to init the player:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.audio) {
        this.audio = this.audio.nativeElement;

        let audioJS = videojs(this.audio,
          {
            fluid: true,
            plugins: {
              wavesurfer: {
                src: this.audioSource,
                msDisplayMax: 10,
                debug: true,
                waveColor: 'grey',
                progressColor: 'black',
                cursorColor: 'black',
                hideScrollbar: true
              }
            }
          }, () => { }
        );
      }
  }
```

But console prints the following error:

> Error: plugin "wavesurfer" does not exist.

So, I changed the object to:

```
fluid: true,
plugins: { VideojsWavesurfer }
```

And apparently recognized the plugin, but now I get this error (I said that apparently it recognized the plugin because this error came from `videojs.wavesurfer.min.js`):

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "WaveSurfer"

I've already tried to add `WaveSurfer` to imports on `app.components.ts` but nothing changes. So, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution on Github [here](https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js/issues/761)

Which is something like

[image]

Comment: It working! I chose to use WaveSurfer directly without using Video.js for audios, and this solution helped me a lot! Thank you so much! (I need to wait more 5 hours to give you the bounty)

Comment: It's okay brother more important things is to solve your problem